# iOS - Bypass Pairing alert for bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, pairing

I'm using Core Bluetooth framework in my iOS app to communicate securely with BT devices. In my product, server sends a pairing code that user has to enter in the text box in peripheral device’s alert to complete the pairing process. It's working good.
As server sends the code, without showing the pairing alert, can I by-pass the alert and handle the code that pairs the device without user's intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you are using encryption on any of your characteristics an attempt to read or write that characteristic will trigger the iOS pairing dialog.

Your app has no direct access to the pairing process as it happens outside of your app.

Comment: What is the delegate method that will trigger the diagog. After entering the pairing digits, will it call any other delegate method?

Comment: There is no specific delegate method